# Find duplicates in a matrix

Tags: matlab

consider a matrix:

```
a = [1 2 
     1 3
     2 3
     4 5
     6 1]
```

I want to find duplicates for every unique element of `a` and take the rows of them to different matrices. For example here lets say that the answer for number 1 is:

```
a1 = [1 2
      1 3
      6 1]
```

The answer for number 2 is:

```
a2 = [1 2
      2 3]
```

The answer for number 3 is:

```
a3 = [1 3
      2 3]
```

and so on for every unique elements of matrix `a`. Any suggestions?

Comment: Shouldn't the answer for number `2` be this: `[1 2; 2 3]` ?

Comment: Yes sorry my fault. I've corrected it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `any` to check if any element of a row contains the value you want. This will return a logical array that is `true` where the row contained the value. You can then use this to grab the relevant rows of `a`.

```
result = a(any(a == value, 2), :);
```

We could create an anonymous function that does this for you.

```
rows_that_contain_value = @(A, value)A(any(A == value, 2), :);
```

Then we can use this like this

```
a = [1 2 
     1 3
     2 3
     4 5
     6 1]

a1 = rows_that_contain_value(a, 1);
a2 = rows_that_contain_value(a, 2);
a3 = rows_that_contain_value(a, 3);
```

If we want to do this for all unique values in `a`, we can do something like the following.

```
groups = arrayfun(@(x)rows_that_contain_value(a, x), unique(a), 'uniformoutput', 0);
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

This will do it:

```
temp=unique(a);
for k=1:numel(temp)
    [r,~]=find(a==temp(k));
    assignin('base', ['a' num2str(k)], a(sort(r),:)) 
end
```

**Results:-**

```
>> a1

a1 =

     1     2
     1     3
     6     1

>> a2

a2 =

     1     2
     2     3

>> a3

a3 =

     1     3
     2     3

>> a4

a4 =

     4     5

>> a5

a5 =

     4     5

>> a6

a6 =

     6     1
```

Comment: Thanks Sardar_Usama